# How to show that a linear program has no maximum?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, simplex

Suppose you have a standard maximum program, where the constants on the right hand side are nonnegative. Suppose further that a variable  occurs on the objective with positive coefficient, but appears in no other constraint. Show that the program has no maximum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the variable $x$ is unconstrained and in the objective function, then obviously you can set its value as large as you want : the problem has no maximum.

For example : maximize $f(x,y)=x+y$ subject to $y\le 4$ is unbounded.

Comment: what about feasibility?

Comment: If the $x$ variable appears in no constraint then we’re good. For the other variables, indeed, we must make sure a feasible solution exists! Great comment

Comment: I left it as a puzzle, but if "the constants on the right hand side are nonnegative", then $x=0$ is feasible.